# ROS Answers SE migration: tf rviz camera

Tags: rviz, camera, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I need to se the position of a ball in rviz using mi camera and tf. The thing is that i have the open cv code but i do not have idea how to create a code for tf that subscribe into my image (from OpenCv) and show it on Rviz. I already saw to much codes about tf publisher and listener, and i still have no idea how to use it.

Please can somebody help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274110/tf-rviz-camera/) by [ANDRO](https://answers.ros.org/users/32353/andro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2017-10-25**:
This should give you some idea [ros message filter](https://answers.ros.org/question/273398/tf2_ros-message-filter-call-back-function-is-never-called/). But remember this isn't working because call back is never called for some reason which i couldn't identify.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-26**:
What particular part you don't understand? If you have position of detected object with respect to camera you just create tf publisher publishing transformation between camera tf frame and object. Of course you also need camera's tf publisher if you don't have it written already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the answer is on a question that you made about 3 days ago.

https://answers.ros.org/question/273792/hi-i-wanto-to-meake-a-program-that-give-the-position-of-a-red-ball-in-2d-with-rviz/

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0